# lambda - 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'xxx'

Tags: python, django, lambda

I am filtering multiple models and chaining them together and sorting them by their attributes.

```
bs = Book.objects.filter(books__person=person).order_by('-release_date') 
jn = Journal.objects.filter(journals__person=person).order_by('-year') 

joined = itertools.chain(x for x in (bs, jn))
sorter = lambda x: x.release_date if hasattr(x,'release_date') else x.year
sorted_medien = sorted(joined, key = sorter, reverse=True)
```

but it is saying: `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'year'`. which is reasonable because i am passing a Queryset and not an object to sorter function.

How can I go deeper and apply the sorter to each object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing something like:

```
>>> bs, jn = [1, 2], [3, 4]
>>> list(itertools.chain(x for x in [bs, jn]))
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

What you want do is:

```
>>> list(itertools.chain(bs, jn))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

So, you need to change `joined = itertools.chain ...` line as follow:

```
joined = itertools.chain(bs, jn)
```